# Creating a Firefox extension to edit "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"

Tags: sharepoint, firefox

On the sharepoint site we're developing at work, people are able to log into the site using IE 7, but when prompted for the username and password on firefox 3, it doesn't matter how many times you try to log on, the username/pass window keeps popping up. If you click cancel it denies you access into the site.
We've tried to fix the issue for our individual machines by:

1) logging into IE 7, clicking "save password" when logging in.

2) Then going into firefox, typing about:config,

3) Search for URIs

4) Adding ".csom.umn.edu" to the value column for the three results that popup.

This is a long and complicated procedure for our clients, would it be possible to create an extension or add-on that would automate this procedure just by downloading it after the first failure of logging on with firefox?

Thank you!

Comment: have you been able to write an extension?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/

Comment: This site talks about pass-through authentication. In Firefox about:config, search for this: network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris and enter ".csom.umn.edu"